# Как узнать адрес метки в lss файле?

Tags: ассемблер, avr, atmel-studio

При компиляции проекта на ассемблере в atmel-studio появляется .lss файл. В нём мне нужно найти адреса всех меток. Возможно ли это сделать программно или же придётся считать что-то руками? Открыв файл в notepad появились какие-то пары адресов, что это может быть ?

```
000000 ef4f                        ser R20          
000001 bb4a                        out DDRA, R20  
000002 bb47                        out DDRB, R20  
000003 bb44                        out DDRC, R20  //настройка на выход
000004 bb41                        out DDRD, R20  
000005 9540                        com R20      
000006 bb4b                        out PORTA, R20  
000007 bb48                        out PORTB, R20  //установка нулей
000008 bb45                        out PORTC, R20  
000009 bb42                        out PORTD, R20  

                                 start:  
00000a e950                        ldi R21, 144 ;a1
00000b e86f                        ldi R22, 143 ;a2
00000c e374                        ldi R23, 52 ;a3
00000d 9552                        SWAP R21
00000e 9562                        SWAP R22
00000f 9572                        SWAP R23  
000010 bb5b                        out PORTA, R21
000011 bb68                        out PORTB, R22  
000012 bb75                        out PORTC, R23  
000013 1b56                        SUB R21, R22  
000014 1b57                        SUB R21, R23  
000015 bb52                        out PORTD, R21   
                                 stop:
                                   ;nop
```

Answer (score 1):

```
00000a e950                        ldi R21, 144 ;a1
```

Здесь 00000a - это и есть адрес инструкции, e950 - это её представление в машинном коде.
То есть отсюда можно заключить, что поскольку метка `start:` находится перед этой инструкцией, 0x00000A и есть адрес этой метки.

Но помимо .lss файла, у вас ещё должен быть .map файл в котором как раз перечислены все символы во всех секциях.